# Running Eval within Nested For Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, eval

I am trying to run eval functions within nested for loops. For example, in the code below, to get item2.length, item2[x].create() must be run with the eval. The create is a custom functionality that I have written in. It works when I test in console. I know that there is alot of stigma associated with using eval. But please disregard that for this case. I just want to know why the evals are not working within nested for loops.

When I run the code, it throws me an error that it cannot get the length of item2[x]. But when I test out the length of item2[x] in console, it gives me the correct length. Why is my code not running properly? It seems that the nested loops are run before the first eval is finished. Please advise.

```
            for (var x = 0; x < item1.length; x++) {
                eval("item2[x].create()");
                for (var y = 0; y < item2[x].length; y++) {
                    eval("item3[x][y].create()");
                    for (var z = 0; z < item3[x][y].length; z++) {
                        eval("item4[x][y][z].create()");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you think that you need to use `eval` at all?

Comment: I understand the risks with eval. But it makes it easier here. Please disregard eval risks for question's sake.

Comment: Why would it be easier? What does `eval("item2[x].create()");` do that `item2[x].create();` doesn't do?

Comment: you're right... I've removed the evals, does the same thing. But the same issue still persists. I'm able to get the .length value in console after everything is loaded. But still getting undefined for y < item2[x].length.

Comment: You are confusing `item1` and `item2`. (All your variable names are off-by-one.)

Comment: Where do you create item2, item3 and item4?
item1[x] seems ok, but, item2[x], from nothing, doesn't seem will work. Same with others.

Comment: Those are just sample items, the issue is that I'm able to get the length of item2[x] nested 1 level deep in Chrome console. But its throwing me an error that the length of item2[x] is undefined when running the loop. Why am I able to get in in console, but throwing me undefined when executing the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the [`create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function is incorrect. Are you sure you are even able to get the length of item2[x] nested 1 level deep?

The `Object.create` function expects an argument which forms the prototype of the new object being created. A simple example looks like this:

```
var parentObj = {
    value: 1, 
    getValue: function(){
        return this.value;
    }
};
var childObj = Object.create(parentObj);
```

If you are not interested in inheriting from an existing prototype, you can pass in `null` as the prototype:

```
var myObj = Object.create(null);
```

Alternately, you can use [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
var testObj = function(){
    this.value = 1;
    this.getValue = function(){
        return this.value;
    };
};
var myObj = new testObj();
```